# Can you create a Runtime Query in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to create a query in TFS that prompts you for query parameters at runtime?

E.G. A query named  "[TeamMember] Undone Tasks" where TFS prompts you for the team memeber at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - this is not possible at the moment in TFS 2008 and I haven't seen that feature in any of the TFS 2010 beta's either.  I have seen it asked for before though so I'm sure the team know that it would be a nice thing to have.

You could use the API, a query in Excel or [hook Excel into the datawarehouse](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html)  to give you that type of data if you wanted it.